# Im not sure why this code is not working properly as it's supossed

Tags: java

```
public String createHash()
{
String[] ALPHABET={"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z","A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
String[] hash={"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7"};
for(int var=0; var==61; var++)
{
   hash[7]=ALPHABET[var];
   System.out.print(hash[7]);
}
return "Success";
}
```

I'm not quiet sure how to explain what this code is supossed to do but I hope you get what I wanted it to do. It's supposed to take the value behinde index 7 of hash and replace it with the value behinde index "var" of ALPHABET.

So at the end it should print in the cosole something like this: "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"

I'm not sure where the error is. It's probabbly something extremly basic but I'm quiet new to programming...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to do. If you just want to print all characters in `ALPHABET`, what do you need `hash` for?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: "for(int var=0; var==61; var++)" - you need to re-read the chapter on for loops.

Comment: @OldProgrammer There is no Error. It returns "Success" as it should but there is not Error.

Comment: The middle part of a for loop is a continuation condition, it will only go to the next step of the loop if `var==61` - how often does that happen if `var = 0`?

Comment: `var==61` is `false` and the loop is supposed to never start

Comment: @Thomas I want the last value of hash to be replaced with the first value of ALPHABET. Than with the second, third, fourth,... When it gets to the last value, here Z, I want it to get reset back to 0 and to change the value of hash[6] to 1. This cycle should repeat thru the whole thing so at the end I would get ZZZZZZZZ. I want it to tell me each and every combination possible. And yes I know there are 62^8 possibilities.

Comment: Could you please refine your question title to make it more concrete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're seeing "Success", aren't you? This may be because of the abort-variable. var is never 61 because this condition will be checked before your for-block is executed.
It will has to be

```
for(int var = 0; var <= 61; var++)
```

if you want 62 executions of your for loop.

Anyway, I don't understand the purpose.

Comment: "var is never 61 because this condition will be checked before your for-block is executed" That was my error. I though it first set var to 0 than went thru the whole block, increased var by 1 and checked if it was 61 and because it's 1 just went on until var was 61. Thanks alot

Comment: Yup. This would be the case in a do-while-Loop! :)